# Deserialize deep-nested arrays

Tags: c#, mongodb, json.net

Currently, I have this json structure:

```
{
    key1: value1,
    key2:
        [
            {key3: value3}
            {key4: value4}
        ]
}
```

and deserialize it into the types

```
IDictionary<string, object>
IDictionary<string, IList<Dictionary<string, object>>>
```

using a CustomCreationConverter:

```
public class NestedArrayConverter : CustomCreationConverter<IList<Dictionary<string, object>>>
{
    public override IList<Dictionary<string, object>> Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);

        return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Now I need to go one level deeper, e.g. plugging another array into value3. This is arbitrary, so value4 can be something different. How could this be done?

In the end I write the data to MongoDB and the driver doesn't work if the type is JArray or JObject. However I need structured data, a string is not enough.

Comment: Why is a string not enough? Can't you just write a string with JSON to the database?

Comment: The data needs to be queryable on the first level, e.g. for value1. That rules out to convert the whole thing into a string. It could be partially a string, though. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's no built-in way of de-/serializing deep-nested json into anything other than JObject/JArray. So I use strings instead. I suppose one could write a converter to handle everything, however not needed in my case.

```
public class NestedArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value.GetType() == typeof(List<string>))
        {
            var list = (List<string>)value;
            writer.WriteStartArray();

            foreach (var str in list)
                writer.WriteRawValue(str);

            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteValue(value);
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            reader.Read();
            var value = new List<string>();

            while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
            {
                value.Add(JObject.Load(reader).ToString());
                reader.Read();
            }

            return value;
        }

        return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```